# Angular6: Why is `ActivatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams` empty when the url clearly shows correct value?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular6

from one page, I call:

```
// call this to nav to '/list' with queryParams 
const data = {'map-center': this.loc.join(',')};
this.router.navigate(['/list'], {queryParams:data} );
```

which produces the correct navigation event with this url:

`http://localhost:8100/list?map-center=13.7414025,100.51102500000002`

but in the target page, `queryParam` is empty in both cases:

```
// <ion-router-outlet main
//      (activate)="!!$event.viewWillEnter ? $event.viewWillEnter() : undefined"

viewWillEnter(){
    // using constructor(){ private route: ActivatedRoute }
    const mapCenter = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['map-center'];
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(p=>console.log(">>> queryParams=", p))
}
```

however, queryParam is fine when I reload from the browser. what's happening?

**[update]** if I add a param to the url, `queryParams` works fine.

```
this.router.navigate(['/list',{a:1}], {queryParams:data} );
// http://localhost:8100/list;a=1?map-center=13.7414025,100.51102500000002
```

Comment: Try `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params =>console.log(params['map-center']))`

Comment: It's the same. I get `params=={}`

Comment: Yes. But I'm returning to the route, so it should already be loaded, right?

Comment: Technically yes. And it worked for me.

Comment: adding a param to the the route makes `queryParams` work fine. 
 e.g. `this.router.navigate(['/list',{a:1}], {queryParams:data} );`